# JQL: Find the latest closed sprint

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

How can I find the last closed sprint?I tried using

```
ORDER BY updatedDate DESC
```

but this returns all the closed sprints. I need only the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA does not provide a JQL function out of the box that supports listing the issues in the last completed sprint. The best it offers is displaying the issues in a sprint by name, e.g.:

```
sprint = "<sprint name>"
```

You can find the documentation about the JQL support for the [sprint field here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver073/advanced-searching-fields-reference-861256237.html#Advancedsearching-fieldsreference-SprintSprint).

If you use JIRA standalone, then there are a few add-ons that provide additional JQL functions. For example, [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) adds a function [previousSprint](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_previoussprint) that does what you want. Your JQL then looks like:

```
issueFunction in previousSprint("<board name>")
```

There is also a cloud version of this add-on, but it does not support the agile functions yet. To see what they do support, [check this table](http://scriptrunner-docs.connect.adaptavist.com/jiracloud/jql-aliases.html#__a_id_comparison_a_comparison_with_scriptrunner_for_jira_server).

Comment: Any alternative to Script Runner ?